# HTML page is getting appended to json response

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, ajax

I am sending a json result in response. On the javascript side html page is getting appended after the json.

```
 HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
 response.setContentType("application/json");
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("success",true);
 response.getWriter().write(jsonObject.toString());
```

On the js side following is the code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "saveFullAdresss?ajax=true",
data: postData,
success: function(result){
if (result["success"]) {
      $(".alert").css("display", "block").addClass("alert-
       success").html("Successfully set status!");
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
       window.location = document.referrer;
} else {
      var except = "";
      $(".alert").css("display", "block").addClass("alert-
       danger").html("Error while saving status!! " + except);
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
 }
},
error: function(result){
    $(".alert").css("display", "block").addClass("alert-
     danger").html("Could not figure out what happend!!");
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
                    },
});
```

In the success I am getting html page response appended with `success:true`. Could some please let me know why this is happening and how to solve this problem.

[image: Following is the result that I am getting]

Following is the screenshot of the response tab:

[image]

Comment: Can you print the result

Comment: @Joyson I have attached the screenshot of the result printed on the console as well as the screenshot of the response tab

Comment: Hi i have updated my answer kindly check

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `die()` after you return the json data back to AJAX call.

e.g.: In PHP

echo $json_data;
die();

Comment: I am using struts2 so I am not sending the response explicitly(I am just setting it). After setting the response data I am sending the string which is configured in struts.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the json as result try updating your js with datatype in ajax call `dataType: "json",`

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "saveFullAdresss?ajax=true",
data: postData,
dataType: "json",
success: function(result){
 ...
},...
```

In your url your controller or core server code linked with `saveFullAdresss` is continue executing that's y you getting the html content on your website. Can you check your backend server code for your request and after response kindly stop the continuing execution by `die();` method or `return` statement. Thank you Hope this will help.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: i have updated the answer kindly check it @IshanTiwary